# Как сделать несколько условий if в pascal

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
var
a,b,c,d:integer;
begin
readln(a);
readln(b);
readln(c);
readln(d);
if a < b and c and d then
  writeln(a);
if b < a and c and d then
  writeln(b);
if c < d and a and b then
  writeln(c);
if d < c and a and b then
  writeln(d);
end.
```

Целью команды является вывод наименьшего из вводимых чисел, однако программа не выводит ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скобки. Используйте скобки и простые условия в них:

```
var
  a, b, c, d: Integer;
begin
  readln(a);
  readln(b);
  readln(c);
  readln(d);
  if (a < b) and (a < c) and (a < d) then
    writeln(a);
  if (b < a) and (b < c) and (b < d) then
    writeln(b);
  if (c < d and (c < a) and (c < b) then
    writeln(c);
  if (d < c) and (d < a) and (d < b) then
   writeln(d);
end.
```